# How can I make my dynamic microphone work on my MacBook Pro with those splitters?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, microphone

I can't get my dynamic microphone to work on my MacBook Pro A1502.
It is a Moukey Dynamic Microphone with a 3.5 mm Jack.
How do I go about it?

I have a headphone splitter and a 3.5 mm male-to-female audio cable. I have also have a 2nd splitter that splits microphone from stereo.

Still, I cannot recognize the microphone on the MacBook. Any suggestion?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "dynamic microphone" is like saying "fast car" add the make and model of the mic to your original question. And, off the top of my head, plugging the mic into a pre-amp or mixer first and then via USB into your Mac might be something worth looking into

Comment: It is a Moukey Dynamic Microphone with a 3.5 mm Jack.

Comment: @SteveChambers - actually 'dynamic' does tell you one thing; that it doesn't need phantom power. The trouble with that particular mic is it has a TRS with no explanation. the OP posted a similar Q on sound design & there can be no answer until the pinout on that TRS is known. All the versions of the mic I can find online have a standard unbalanced TS.